# Google's Geocoder returns wrong country for US zip codes 08644

Tags: jquery, google-geocoder

I am using google geocoder to auto complete city and state using zip codes. I am using { 'address': _query + ' ,US' }. It is returning address starting with 08644 instead of city with that zip code.

Comment: Some more relevant code would be great.

Comment: Call to geocoder 
var options = {
               componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' }
        
    };
    $('#' + field).geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, options).result(function (_event, _data) {

Answer (score 1):

According to the United States Postal Service, 08644 is not a valid zip code:

[Source](https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=08644&zip=)